# Set same view for two different figures

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm having two figures in Matlab. The problem as shown in the figure [image: diff]  that they have different views and scale in the axis. This is the code I'm using `Figure; axis vis3d; view(3); grid on` so if anyone could please advise how can I make them standard where they'll have the same view and same axis values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the axis limits equal:

```
figure(1)
plot(...);
set(gca,'xlim',[a, b],'ylim',[c, d],'zlim',[e, f]);
view(g,h)


figure(2)
plot(...);
set(gca,'xlim',[a, b],'ylim',[c, d],'zlim',[e, f]);
view(g,h)
```

If you want to control also the ticks you can use:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'1', '10', '100'},'YTickLabel',{'1', '10', '100'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`linkprop`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/linkprop.html) function:

```
figure; axis vis3d; view(3); grid on, h(1) = gca; 
figure; axis vis3d; view(3); grid on, h(2) = gca; 

linkprop(h, {'view', 'xlim', 'ylim', 'zlim'})
```

Comment: the problem is the two figures are run in two different times, so I can't link them

Comment: I tried it at for me it seems to work. Can you edit your question to include the code you are using to create the figures?